# Selecting workbook and find/replace

Tags: vba, excel

There is actually two questions in this post. Thank you in advance.

My first problem is that I cannot seem to get Excel to choose the Excel workbook that is named "(DATES)-Usage", where (DATES) changes each day.

Second problem is that the `.Replace` Object is giving me and `Run-Time error '438': Object doesn't support this property method`. Could someone please take a look and tell me where I am making my mistakes. Thank you again!

```
Sub UsersBySource_Update()

  ' Create variables
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim unspecified As String
  Dim organic As String
  Dim TheString As String, Cohort As Date

  ' Ask user for cohort date and return an error if invalid date is entered
  TheString = Application.InputBox("Please Specify The Cohort:")

  If IsDate(TheString) Then
      Cohort = DateValue(TheString)
  Else
      MsgBox ("Invalid Date")
  End If

  ' Set variables
  unspecified = "[Unspecified]"
  organic = "Organic"

  ' Activate the workbook
  For Each wb In Workbooks
      If wb.Name Like "*-Usage" Then
          wb.Activate
      End If
  Next

  ' Find and Replace the unspecified and organic variables in the workbook
  ActiveSheet.Replace What:=unspecified, Replacement:=organic, LookAt _
  :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False

  ' Add Columns and Row to fix formatting to continue
  Columns("B:E").Insert shift:=xlToRight
  Range("B2").EntireRow.Insert

  ' Copy and Paste initial date range to start program
  Range("A3").Select
  Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
  Selection.Copy
  Range("B3").Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
  :=True, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the `Replace` method acts upon a range, not a worksheet.

Comment: Now that you have your answer (yay!), I **highly** suggest reading through, and implementing, [avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros). It will make your code tighter, less prone to errors, and will teach you how to work directly with your data. This will allow your macro to run faster as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
ActiveSheet.Replace What:=unspecified, Replacement:=organic, LookAt _ :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

to the following

```
ActiveSheet.Cells.Replace What:=unspecified, Replacement:=organic, LookAt _ :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you said that you want a find a **Sheet** that's like *(DATES)-Usage*, but you're looking in Workbooks:

```
 For Each wb In Workbooks
      If wb.Name Like "*-Usage" Then
          wb.Activate
      End If
  Next
```

Try it like this: *(edited)*

```
 For Each ws In Worksheets
      If ws.Name Like "*-Usage" Then
          Exit For
      End If
  Next
```

Accoriding to MSDN: [Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx), is a Range method.

So instead of this:

```
ActiveSheet.Replace What:=unspecified, Replacement:=organic, LookAt _
  :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

Try this:

```
ws.Cells.Replace What:=unspecified, Replacement:=organic, LookAt _
      :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
```

Cheers.

Comment: You mean `ws.Cells.Replace...`? I'd stay away from `ActiveSheet`, and use a variable instead .

Comment: Sorry i did mean Workbooks.

Comment: You would have to quit the Foreach for that to work. If any other sheet follows the Date-Usage sheet it would try to use that one. 
I'll edit my comment to reflect that.

Comment: No worries. I found out the problem. It is a .csv file, so i just added. *-Usage.csv and it worked. Thank you though!

Comment: Workbook.Name should not return the extension though.

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines

```
Range("A3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
```

to these lines

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range(Range("A3"), Range("A3").End(xlDown)).Copy
    .Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=True
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

You do not need all the `Select` methods.